# Update view (ViewBags) ASP MVC after Dropdown List change

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

It's my first asp MVC project that I do. I'm used to develop in JAVA and it's easier to update values. I can for example  do MyeditText.set or anything.set to change a value.

My problem is : I use a login page on my web application, A person log on with a username and a password, after I do a redirection to an assessment (a form)

```
private Db database = new Db();

    //
    // GET: /Assessment/
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to your assessment ";
        int assessment = 1;

        // DropDownList TYPE ANSWER
        string queryTA = "Select distinct TA.type_answer_id, TA.type_name from pfi_type_answer TA, pfi_assessment ASS, pfi_form FO, pfi_contain_answer CA, pfi_contain_question CQ, pfi_question QU where ASS.form_id = FO.form_id and FO.form_id = CQ.form_id and CQ.question_id = QU.question_id and QU.question_id = CA.question_id and TA.type_answer_id = CA.type_answer_id and ASS.assessment_id = "+ assessment;
        List<SelectListItem> DropListTA = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<object[]> ListTA = database.Select(queryTA);

        foreach (object[] s in ListTA)
        {
            DropListTA.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = s[1].ToString(), Value = s[0].ToString() });
        }


        ViewBag.formListTA = DropListTA;

        // DropDownList LANGUAGE
        string queryL = "SELECT * FROM PFI_LANGUAGE";
        List<SelectListItem> DropListL = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<object[]> ListL = database.Select(queryL);

        foreach (object[] s in ListL)
        {
            DropListL.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = s[1].ToString(), Value = s[0].ToString() });
        }

        ViewBag.formListL = DropListL;

        int TypeAnswer = (int)ListTA.ElementAt(0).GetValue(0);


        string queryC = "Select count(*) from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and TA.type_answer_id= " + TypeAnswer;
        //Select count(*) from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA, pfi_assessment ASS, pfi_form FO, pfi_question QU, pfi_contain_question CQ, pfi_contain_answer CA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and ASS.form_id = FO.form_id and FO.form_id = CQ.form_id and QU.question_id = CQ.question_id and QU.question_id = CA.question_id and AN.answer_id = CA.answer_id and TA.type_answer_id = 1 and ASS.assessment_id = 1;
        int countAnswers = database.Count(queryC);
        ViewBag.countAnswersVB = countAnswers;

        //String[] tableValue = new String[countAnswers];
        //string queryAn = "Select answer from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and TA.type_answer_id=  " + TypeAnswer;
        string queryAn = "Select answer from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA, pfi_assessment ASS, pfi_form FO, pfi_question QU, pfi_contain_question CQ, pfi_contain_answer CA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and ASS.form_id = FO.form_id and FO.form_id = CQ.form_id and QU.question_id = CQ.question_id and QU.question_id = CA.question_id and TA.type_answer_id = CA.type_answer_id and ASS.assessment_id = 1 and TA.type_answer_id = " + TypeAnswer +  " group by answer";
        List<object[]> ListAn = database.Select(queryAn);
        ViewBag.tableHeaderVB = ListAn;


        //Question and Radio buttons
        String queryQ = "Select distinct question_number, question from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA, pfi_assessment ASS, pfi_form FO, pfi_question QU, pfi_contain_question CQ, pfi_contain_answer CA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and ASS.form_id = FO.form_id and FO.form_id = CQ.form_id and QU.question_id = CQ.question_id and QU.question_id = CA.question_id and TA.type_answer_id = CA.type_answer_id and ASS.assessment_id = 1 and TA.type_answer_id = " + TypeAnswer;
        List<object[]> ListQuestion = database.Select(queryQ);
        ViewBag.questionVB = ListQuestion;

        return View();
    }
```

This is the code of my controller for the index page,

The code for the cshtml page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#formListL').change(function () {
        var selectedLanguage = $(this).val();
        alert("Alert Box Language " + selectedLanguage);
    });

    $('#formListTA').change(function () {
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();
        var selectedLanguage = $('#formListL').val();
        //alert("Alert Box Type Answer " + selectedVal);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Assessment/Index",
            data: { 'valueTA': selectedVal, 'valueL': selectedLanguage },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Alert Box Type Answer " + selectedVal);
            }
        });
     });
});
```

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome to your assessment";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>

<label>Answers</label>
@Html.DropDownList("formListTA")
<label class= "marge_left">Language</label>
@Html.DropDownList("formListL")



@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class ="containTable">
<table border="1" frame="void" rules="rows" class= "assess">
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    @foreach (object[] s in ViewBag.tableHeaderVB)
    {
        <th>
            @s[0]
        </th>
    }
    </tr>


    @foreach (object[] q in ViewBag.questionVB)
    {
    <tr>

        <td>
            @q[0].
        </td>

        <td>
            <a href="#***" class= "linkTable" id= @q[0]>@q[1]</a>
        </td>

            @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.countAnswersVB; i++)
            {
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name=@q[0] id=@q[0]@i class="css-checkbox" />
            <label for=@q[0]@i class="css-label"></label>
        </td>
            }

    </tr>
    }

</table>
</div>

<div class = "Submit">
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</div>

}
```

Everything is working and I obtain what I want

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/16/1397592205-pritn1.png

Now I want to be abble to refresh the table if I change the value of my drop-down lists, for example, if I change the value of answer's drop-down list.

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/16/1397592206-pritn2.png

I juste want to refresh the table, for this I tried to do a JavaScript Function (you can see it on the cs-html file) and I did a new Index method :

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(String valueTA, String valueL)
    {

        int value = Convert.ToInt32(valueTA);
        int valueLan = Convert.ToInt32(valueL);
        int assessment = 1;

        // DropDownList TYPE ANSWER
        string queryTA = "Select distinct TA.type_answer_id, TA.type_name from pfi_type_answer TA, pfi_assessment ASS, pfi_form FO, pfi_contain_answer CA, pfi_contain_question CQ, pfi_question QU where ASS.form_id = FO.form_id and FO.form_id = CQ.form_id and CQ.question_id = QU.question_id and QU.question_id = CA.question_id and TA.type_answer_id = CA.type_answer_id and ASS.assessment_id = " + assessment;
        List<SelectListItem> DropListTA = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<object[]> ListTA = database.Select(queryTA);

        foreach (object[] s in ListTA)
        {
            DropListTA.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = s[1].ToString(), Value = s[0].ToString() });
        }


        // DropDownList LANGUAGE
        string queryL = "SELECT * FROM PFI_LANGUAGE";
        List<SelectListItem> DropListL = new List<SelectListItem>();
        List<object[]> ListL = database.Select(queryL);

        foreach (object[] s in ListL)
        {
            DropListL.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = s[1].ToString(), Value = s[0].ToString() });
        }

        ViewBag.formListL = DropListL;

        ViewBag.formListTA = DropListTA;
        string queryC = "Select count(*) from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and TA.type_answer_id= " + value;
        //Select count(*) from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA, pfi_assessment ASS, pfi_form FO, pfi_question QU, pfi_contain_question CQ, pfi_contain_answer CA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and ASS.form_id = FO.form_id and FO.form_id = CQ.form_id and QU.question_id = CQ.question_id and QU.question_id = CA.question_id and AN.answer_id = CA.answer_id and TA.type_answer_id = 1 and ASS.assessment_id = 1;
        int countAnswers = database.Count(queryC);
        ViewBag.countAnswersVB = countAnswers;

        String queryAn = "Select answer from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA, pfi_assessment ASS, pfi_form FO, pfi_question QU, pfi_contain_question CQ, pfi_contain_answer CA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and ASS.form_id = FO.form_id and FO.form_id = CQ.form_id and QU.question_id = CQ.question_id and QU.question_id = CA.question_id and TA.type_answer_id = CA.type_answer_id and ASS.assessment_id = 1 and TA.type_answer_id = " + value + " group by answer";
        List<object[]> ListAn = database.Select(queryAn);
        ViewBag.tableHeaderVB = ListAn;

        //Question and Radio buttons
        String queryQ = "Select distinct question_number, question from PFI_ANSWER AN, PFI_TYPE_ANSWER TA, pfi_assessment ASS, pfi_form FO, pfi_question QU, pfi_contain_question CQ, pfi_contain_answer CA where TA.type_answer_id = AN.type_answer_id and ASS.form_id = FO.form_id and FO.form_id = CQ.form_id and QU.question_id = CQ.question_id and QU.question_id = CA.question_id and TA.type_answer_id = CA.type_answer_id and ASS.assessment_id = 1 and TA.type_answer_id = " + value;
        List<object[]> ListQuestion = database.Select(queryQ);
        ViewBag.questionVB = ListQuestion;
        //return PartialView();

        return View();
    }
```

I just want to refresh the table (the Viewbags), I'm going into the function  "public ActionResult Index(String valueTA, String valueL)" when I change the value of my drop-down list but nothing happen..

Hope you will help me.
Thank you.

Comment: The reason why this seems so difficult is because you aren't using the MVC pattern correctly, currently your project has VC but no 'M'. To make life easier, make use of models and partial views as much as possible.

Comment: @IlyaNemtsev The "M" in "MVC" does not pertain to view models.

Comment: You are correct, I thought I was being clever with abbreviation, but that View needs a 'View' model.

Comment: The use of view models is one of many things the OP needs to consider but I'd say that the first thing to do would be to narrow down a specific problem as as it stands this is basically a big code dump and the words "help me." I think it's time to take a step back and tackle one thing at a time.

Comment: Heelo, sorry if it looks like it's a big dump code. I just wanted to show you what I did.

The only thing is the creation of a form with radio buttons and two drop-down list. 

I don't create any object here, I don't know how I can use my model here.

The main question if you prefer is to know how can I refresh my table on the same page when I change values on my drop-down list. I think I have to call an ajax function on my javascript but maybe I have to use partial view.. I'm not asking to do my job, just to help me to find a way to do it. 

Hope you will help me guys.

Comment: I found a solution thanks to a partial view. Thanks Ilya Nemtsev